# Mean & std on data frame column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, average, std

For 50 csv files, I need to calculate mean and std for just one specific column. Then I need to create an array of 50 rows and 2 columns so that I will have in each row the std and mean of one of the csv files.
 I am stuck in the level of trying to get mean & std for df of the first csv.

Here is what I have got:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import glob
i=0
path ="C:\\Users\\sharon\\Desktop\\mathematical finance\\sadna"
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
arr = np.zeros((50,2))
for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename,encoding="utf-8")
    df=df.loc[2:470,'Unnamed: 3']
    Mean=df.mean() #DOES NOT WORK
    Std=df.std(axis=1)  # What?...
    arr[i,:]=(Mean,Std)
```

edit:

problem solved with this code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import glob
path ="C:\\Users\\sharon\\Desktop\\mathematical finance\\sadna"
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
df_list = [(pd.read_csv(f, encoding = "utf-8", header = None,usecols = [3], nrows = 470, ).assign(filename = f)) for f in all_files]
final_df = pd.concat(df_list)
final_df[3]= final_df[3].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
agg_df = final_df.groupby(['filename']).agg(['mean', 'std'])
```

Comment: What means `#DOES NOT WORK` ?

Comment: For `Std=df.std(axis=1)` need `Std=df.std()` only

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider building a single data frame using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) across all CSV files that are concatenated together with [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html). Be sure to use needed arguments of [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html). Then aggregate for needed statistics. Finally, convert data frame values to numpy array with [`to_numpy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy):

```
path = "C:\\Users\\sharon\\Desktop\\mathematical finance\\sadna"
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")

# SPECIFY NO HEADERS, SPECIFIC COLUMN AND NUMBER OF ROWS
df_list = [(pd.read_csv(f, encoding = "utf-8", 
                        header = None,
                        usecols = [4], 
                        nrows = 469)
              .assign(filename = f)
           ) for f in all_files]

# COMPILE LARGE DATA FRAME
final_df = pd.concat(df_list, ignore_index=True)

# AGGREGATE BY filename
agg_df = final_df.groupby(['filename']).agg(['mean', 'std'])

# CONVERT TO NUMPY ARRAY
arr = agg_df.to_numpy()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am almost there except this error: NameError: name 'filename' is not defined. How can I define filename?

Comment: Did you include the `assign` call as this answer shows? This creates a column for the corresponding csv file name that you later use in `groupby`.

Comment: At what line does error occur? `df_list` or `final_df`. Hmmmm...check `final_df`. Is there a column named *filename*? If not, check any of the dfs in df_list: `df_list[0]`. Spelling and case matters. Try removing `ignore_index=True`.

Comment: error occurs in line final_df. there is a column named filename. I tried removing ignore_index=True and now there is a new error: ValueError: no results in line of final_df. any idea?

Comment: I see there are rows of nan and rows containing a string, so maybe now that is the problem.

Comment: problem solved as I show in my edition to the question. thanks a lot!

Comment: Very weird! Don't know how `pd.numeric` helps for a string column (btw - does not need to be called in `apply` but directly on column). My guess is some of your CSVs may not have any rows or issues with formatting and so *filename* column is never assigned. I advise you to check data for consistency not just that code runs without error.

Comment: One cleaner way is to filter out the bad dfs in `df_list` after first list comprehension: `df_list = [df for df in df_list if 'filename' in df.columns]`